# Define ORDER in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble getting my sql to pull in photos based on the column "order" which contains numbers. The following works fine, however it seems to be pulling in photos based on the "num" column in "cms_uploads".

```
$photoSql = "SELECT * FROM cms_uploads WHERE ('tableName'='residential_master_rental_availabilities' AND 'recordNum' = '".$rent['num']."' AND 'fieldname' = 'image') LIMIT 1";
```

This query returns nothing:

```
$photoSql = "SELECT * FROM cms_uploads WHERE ('tableName'='residential_master_rental_availabilities' AND 'recordNum' = '".$rent['num']."' AND 'fieldname' = 'image') ORDER BY 'order' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: remove the quotes from your column names

Comment: (except that bacticks are required on reserved words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

You need backticks rather than single quotes for the `order by`.  You are ordering by a constant -- that is, doing nothing:

```
ORDER BY `order`
```

To help with writing code, *only* use single quotes for string constants and dates.